# Canadian Cross binutils To ARM

Tags: linux, cross-platform, arm, mips, cross-compiling

I'm using [JLime](http://jlime.com/) on my HP Jornada 720 that uses a ARM processor. I've already have a [cross-compiled *gcc* for x86](http://jlime.com/mw4/index.php/Download_j700#Crosscompilers)(*arm-linux-gcc*). The idea of what I want to do is very difficult to understand, then take a look at this chart:

> arm-linux-gcc(at my Ubuntu laptop) -> binutils to run on a ARM processor(targeted to compile mips-elf while on my ARM device)

I want to make a *binutils* to run on a ARM Linux device that will compile programs to MIPS Linux.

My questions are:

- How I need to `./configure` this?
- I need to use a extra parameter to *make* or change anything on the MakeFile?
- Did you understood what I want to do? **;-)**

Comment: I understand. You want to compile from your x86 machine a cross-binutils that runs on ARM and works on MIPS files... Shouldn't be too hard. You may wish to build a ARM compiler though and then it should be trivial to build the cross-compiler from the ARM device, rather than trying to build it for 3 different platforms.

Comment: Yeah, but I've already have a binutils on my ARM(that is targeted to ARM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --build=x86 --target=mips-elf
```

I'm not sure what the correct names are for your specific scenario (armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi? i686-pc-linux-gnu?) but cross-building a cross-toolchain is known as a "Canadian Cross".  HTH